# Django How do you get field from another model in a view?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I think this question has been asked a few times already, however, the questions and their answers are not that clear. If you can make the headline question or the example below to be clearer. Please do.

Example:
I have an orchard, within my orchard I have fields of apple trees and these apple trees have apples. The question is using my models:

1. **how do I get the number of apples in a given field**?
2. **total mass of all the apples produced in that given field**?

## Model

```
class Field(models.Model):
   size = models.PositiveIntergerField()
   max_tree_number = models.PositiveIntergerField()

class Tree(models.Model):
   field = models.ForeignKey(Field)
   date_of_planting = models.datefield(editable=False)
   variety = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Apple(models.Model):
   tree = models.ForeignKey(Tree)
   mass = models.PositiveIntergerField()
```

## View

```
class FieldView(generic.ListView):
   template = '[app_name]/index.html'

   def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
       context = super(FieldView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
       context['tree_count'] = Field._meta.model_name
       context['mass'] = ???
       context['apple_count'] = ???
```

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [annotate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/aggregation/#joins-and-aggregates) your queryset with the number of apples and mass.

```
from django.db.models import Count, Sum

def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = super(FieldView, self).get_queryset()
    queryset = queryset.annotate(num_apples=Count('tree__apple'), apple_mass=Sum('tree__apple__mass'))
    return queryset
```

Then, when you loop through the queryset you can access the annotated fields.

```
{% for obj in object_list %}
  {{ obj.size }}, {{ obj.num_apples }}, {{ obj.apple_mass }}
{% endfor %}
```

Note that you haven't had to add anything to the context in `get_context_data`, so you might be able to remove it from your view.

Comment: Thank you for your help, however I am having issues with self.object.   >>AttributeError: 'FIELDVIEW' object has no attribute 'object'. Have I missed something obvious?

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question before and thought you had a detail view for a particular orchard. Which orchard do you want to know the results for? Every orchard in the list?

Comment: The end goal is to have a page. With the field with the number of apples next to it.      >> Field.  Apples.    >>Field1  100 >>field2 200 >>so on...       You are totally right what I asked, but self.object is not returning an object. Just wondering if I am missing any key lines of code to make it happen.

Comment: That's expected. List views are for displaying a list of objects, so they don't set `self.object`. I've updated my answer to show how you can use annotate for a list view.